# I can no longer boot into Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

I just installed the latest LTS version of Ubuntu. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvBZBfY5Pfc). My motherboard is an 'MB Gigabyte GA-970A-UD3' (UEFI). I reserved unallocated space for Ubuntu and chose the option to "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10". I don't have the option to boot into Windows on the Grub menu.

Comment: Your questions has serious issues, the main one being lack of information. Please edit and add informations about your hardware (some require tweaks for dual boot), is the Windows 10 factory installed and if so have you read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and how did you installed Ubuntu (Legacy or UEFI)? etc. There's no "main" partition, just partitions. And regardless of what you did in Windows by reserving unallocated space, if you then chose "Erase... and install Ubuntu" the installer did just that.

Comment: For the record and complementing the above: You cannot "make a partition for Ubuntu" from Windows. What you can and should do in Windows is to use its own native tools to shrink one or more partitions thus leaving unallocated space for Ubuntu to use. Unallocated space is exactly what it means, it's NOT a partition.

Comment: I'm sorry. Thanks for you useful help and advice!

Comment: Open a Terminal and do *sudo update-grub*. If it doesn't find Windows still other troubleshooting is needed. Have you boot the Ubuntu live session (and installed) in UEFI mode as well?

Comment: Terminal output(only the line with windows): 'Found Windows 10 (loader) on /dev/sda1'

Comment: Windows 10 shows up on the menu again, testing rn edit: I had to boot into Windows 10 twice but it works now. Thanks, I'm really grateful :)

Comment: You should be good to go :)